# Windows server CAL for accessing tcp ports

Tags: windows-server-2008, license

Is there any license for accessing the TCP port from a server without accessing the folders?

Whether CAL is required for that?

I do have 2 windows server OS license and I have 1 user CAL for the same. Can I use both the servers with single CAL? Or I need separate CALs for each server?
I didn't find any document for this in Microsoft site

Comment: Have you spoken to Microsoft or your reseller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned User CALs specifically, I'll stick to just those.  Device CALs are similar, and for the most part you can replace "User" with "Device" in the sentences below. :)

> Is there any license for accessing the TCP port from a server without accessing the folders?

In general, yes. Any connection(s) to the server by a user requires a CAL.

There is a couple variations on this though.  Like External Connector licenses, Per Core licenses, and Web servers.

Basically, if you authenticate users as Windows users (even if by proxy through another software) then you need CALs for each of those users.

> I do have 2 windows server OS license and I have 1 user CAL for the same. Can I use both the servers with single CAL?

Yes, you can use that 1 user Server CAL to allow 1 user access to any Server OS you own, as long as it's the same version (or earlier) than the CAL is for.

So if you have a Windows 2008 user CAL, that single CAL covers that user connecting to any 200/2003/2008 server you own.  If you want to add a Windows 2012 server, then you would need a 2012 CAL, which will then cover 2012/08/03/00.   in that case, your pre-existing 2008 CAL would still be valid/usable, just not for connecting to the 2012 server.

More info from MS:

- [About Licensing - Client Access Licenses and Management Licenses](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/client-access-license.aspx)
- [A Guide to Assessing Windows Server Licensing](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/8/9/68964284-864d-4a6d-aed9-f2c1f8f23e14/Assessing_Windows_Server_Licensing.docx)